# ./src/actions/productActions.js Attempted import error: 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL' is not exported from '../reducers/productReducers'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

i have tried many times to solve this error, but i couldn't do it.
with it I don't know what to do next. i have tried all the way to get solution but its not working out.

```
 import axios from "axios"
    import  {PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS}  from "../constants/productConstants";
    import {PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS}  from "../reducers/productReducers"
    
    const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) =>{
    try{
        dispatch({type:PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST});
        const {data}= await axios.get("/api/products");
        dispatch({type:PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,payload:data});
    }
    catch(error){
        dispatch({type:PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,payload:error.message});
    }
    }
    const detailsProduct=(productId)=>async(dispatch)=>{
        try {
            dispatch({type:PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,payload:productId});
            const{data} =await axios.get("/api/products/"+productId);
            dispatch({type:PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,payload:data});
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({type:PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,payload:error.message});
        }
    }
    
    
    export default{listProducts,detailsProduct};
```

productReducer:

```
import { PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS } from "../constants/productConstants";

function productListReducer(state= {products:[]},action){

    switch(action.type){
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return{loading:true};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return{loading:false, products:action.payload};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return{loading:false,error:action.payload};
         default:
            return state;
    }
}

export {productListReducer}
```

Comment: Can you please add code of your productReducers file ? It look likes you have not exported that constants from that file.

Comment: I have added sir

Comment: Are there two variants of PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS each? Because in the main component you are importing from productReducers and in productReducer you are importing from productConstants.

Comment: Yes, sir. I am using two variants of it

Comment: what is the solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are trying have imported constants from reducer file but you have not exported them from that file. Also you have imported same constants in reducer file also. I think you are confused about import and export. So try this:

You should have declare all of that constants in ** productConstants** file like this:
**productConstants.js**

```js
export const PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL = 'PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL';
export const PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST = 'PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST';
export const PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS = 'PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS';

export const PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL = 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST = 'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS = 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS';
```

Now, import these constants in your both file **reducer** file and **action** file like this:

**your action file:**

```js
import axios from "axios";
import {
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  // import these also from same file
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/productConstants";

const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products");
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};
const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId });
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products/" + productId);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};

export default { listProducts, detailsProduct };
```

React redux should have a proper file to implement the job easily. I have created here [React Native Redux Skeleton](https://github.com/kishanbharda/ReactReduxSkeleton). Check this for the initial file stucture.

Answer (score 0):

You are not exporting the named constants from `productReducer` file that you are trying to import in your first file. Just do a named export from `productReducer`.

```
import { PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS } from "../constants/productConstants";
//^^ avoid this import if not using anywhere in the file
function productListReducer(state= {products:[]},action){

    switch(action.type){
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return{loading:true};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return{loading:false, products:action.payload};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return{loading:false,error:action.payload};
         default:
            return state;
    }
}

export productListReducer
export const PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL = 'YOUR VALUE HERE'
export const PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST = 'YOUR VALUE HERE'
export const PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS = 'YOUR VALUE HERE'
```

But this might cause name clashes as you are importing constants with similar names in `productReducer`, so it's better to avoid the import if you are not using anywhere else in `productReducer` because the scope of the constants is localized within the reducer function's `switch` case.

Comment: Hurrah!. You're such a intelligent, sir.. I am just a beginner to react. I am studying B.E computer science engineering. Can you please guide me to fortune way

Comment: Glad, the issue is fixed, and thank you for your kind words. There are many good tutorials on YouTube about react by academind, codevolution etc, you can follow the playlists.